# windows phone 8 emulator doesn't connect via vpn

Tags: windows-phone-8

I'm developing a windows phone 8 app in VS2013 and accessing web service via VPN, when I run app from VS2013 it asking for my local watchguard login and connects only via local network.  But my web service available only via VPN.  Rather than using emulator, if I use device it connects VPN directly and working fine.  What causes the issue?.

Please advice.